# Program does not loop an input more than once (Python 3.3)

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

In this small program I have created, I want the program to loop an input until a positive integer is entered. Different outputs are printed when I enter a positive and a negative number, which is what I want. However, when I enter a negative number twice, the loop will break.

For example when I enter -6 once, it will print 'Your distance input is not positive, please enter the distance between the two sensors, in meters'. But when I enter another negative number like -6 or -75, the program continues instead of looping.

I don't know why this happens and I just want answers or feedbacks on why this happens. Please feel free to alter my code so it loops until a positive number is entered.

Here is my program.

```
distance = (0)

while distance == 0:
   distance = int(input('Distance between the two sensors, in meters \n'))
   if distance > 0:
      print ('Your distance is', distance)
   else:
            distance = int(input('Your distance input is not positive, please enter the distance between the two sensors, in meters \n'))

print ('This will only print after the loop')
```

Comment: Let me know if my answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: If you find my answer suitable, you can close the question with the check-mark beside my answer.

Comment: Right. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your program does not loop because your `while` loop breaks when you input a negative number. The only input which will continue your loop is 0. Perhaps you want something like this instead :

```
distance = int(input('Distance between the two sensors, in meters \n'))
while distance <= 0:
    distance = int(input('Your distance input is not positive, please'
            ' enter the distance between the two sensors, in meters\n'))
print ('Your distance is', distance)
```